# what is e^ln(0)

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, logarithms

On the one hand we have the definition of the inverse function:

$f\circ f^{-1} = id$

Combining this with the fact that function composition is associative we get:

$e^{ln(0)} = e\circ(ln ~ 0) = (e\circ ln) ~ 0 = id ~ 0 = 0$

On the other hand, many would claim that since ln(0) is undefined then $e^{ln(0)}$ must also be undefined.

Which is the correct answer?

Comment: Undefined as is. However, the (one-sided) limit of $e^{\ln x}$ as $x\to0^+$ is $0$. In particular, some authors might use the convention of writing $e^{\ln 0}=0$, but they implicitly mean the limit. And the answers are right wrt inverse functions.

Answer (score 2):

The second answer is correct: $e^{\ln 0}$ is undefined because $\ln 0$ is undefined.

The definition of an inverse function says that $f\circ f^{-1}=\text{id}$ *on the domain of $f^{-1}$*, not on all real numbers.

Comment: What problems should i expect if i decide to define it as 0 anyway?

Comment: Not only will you be incorrect, you'll be reinforcing bad habits that will lead you to more incorrect answers in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Only bijective functions have inverses. $ln$ is usually defined by first restricting the domain and codomain of $e^x$ so that it's bijective, and then defining $ln$ to be the inverse on that specific domain and codomain.

However, since $0$ is not in the range of $e^x$, for any codomain that contains $0$, $e^x$ cannot be bijective there so cannot have an inverse.